# Vários eventos em seletor JQuery

Tags: jquery

alguém sabe se/como é possível atribuir vários eventos a um elemento JQuery em uma única linha?

Por exemplo:

```js
$('#elemento')
  .keyup(function(){...})
  .focusout(function(){..});
```

Comment: Podes usar `$('#elemento').on('keyup focusout etc', function(){`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A documentação do [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) diz:

**Sintaxe:**

> **.on(** eventos[, seletor] [, dados], callback **)**

e a descrição de *eventos* diz:

> One or more space-separated event types

ou seja:

> *um ou mais tipos de evento separados por espaços.*

Um exemplo seria:

```
$('#elemento').on('keyup focusout', function(){
```

Comment: Valeu cara, obrigado!

Comment: @LeandroHermesNeto de nada, fico contente de poder ajudar.